# BSOD STOP 0xF4 Dump Fail 0XC0000010

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, safe-mode

```
System Info:

Laptop: HP Envy 15 3040nr
OS Version: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium, Service Pack 1, 64 bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
Processor Count: 8
RAM: 8139 Mb
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series, 1024 Mb
Hard Drives: C: Total - 694222 MB, Free - 401679 MB; D: Total - 20877 MB, Free - 1623 MB; I: Total - 98 MB, Free - 77 MB;
Motherboard: Hewlett-Packard, 1688
```

I have been presented with BSODs shortly after every startup. Unfortunately the BSODs fail to create minidumps. The error codes are the following:

```
STOP: 0x000000F4 (0x3, 0xFFFFFA800B741B30, 0XFFFFFA800B741E10, 0XFFFFF800035D0130)
Physical memory dump failed with status 0XC0000010
```

I am aware that this is the cause of a critical process being terminated, however, because there are no minidumps, I cannot pinpoint the issue to a specific process. I've found some ISCT Agent errors and warnings in Event Viewer with the following info:

Error

```
CDriverApi::GetInterfaceAlias   *****Unable to enumerate device interfaces, error=0x103
```

Error

```
CIRSTDriverApi::CreateInstance   *****Unable to open the IRST device driver
```

Warning

```
CSleepWakeTimeManager::SaveRstSettings   iRST driver does not exist
```

Warning

```
CAgentService::AgentServiceInit   Thermal driver on startup reports current delta 49, threshold 50
```

Safemode runs normally and Safemode with Networking gave me a BSOD once, but hasn't done so since. It might be a hardware issue with the Intel wireless card but it connects to the internet normally before the BSOD and in Safemode with Networking. Updating/reinstalling the card and ISCT drivers does not fix the issue.

After enabling the windows update service in safemode, I tried installing this update http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2541014 as to generate some minidumps. Unfortunately it tells me that the update is not applicable to my computer.

Other things I have tried that have failed are a system restore, startup repair, and disabling the ISCT and card drivers through Device Manager.

**UPDATE:**

I uninstalled iRST as @Ramhound told me to and after using the computer for around 20 minutes, I was presented with the same BSOD as before. I suspected it was a hard drive issue so I scheduled a CHKDSK on boot. Two days later, CHKDSK was still replacing bad clusters. I returned the third day and found a "Boot Device Not Found" screen. I force restarted the computer and CHKDSK started again. A few hours later there was another BSOD, this time "BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO" and again, it was stuck initializing the disk for the crash dump.

For the time being, I only have around 20 minutes of use before I get a 0xF4 BSOD without a minidump being generated. Is it time for a new HDD?

I ran an [HDDStatus status report](http://www.hddstatus.com/hdrepshowreport.php?ReportCode=8941006&ReportVerification=FCDCC868), it seems that I do need a new HDD. Will restoring the contents of my current HDD to a new one bring up the same issue? Can I guarantee that a new HDD will fix my BSODs?

Comment: So what drive is causing the crash?  You can use a program like [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to determine that.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, as I said, minidumps are not being generated, so BlueScreenView would not show me any entries.

Comment: The knowledge base article you linked to involves SCSI devices which are set to handle the hibernation file.  You have made sure [Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927069) is configured to generate the memory dump file correct?  Yes;  I am aware the article is for Windows XP the instructions are identical though.  You wrote `ISCT` I am thinking you actually mean `iRST` which would make a great deal more sense since `iRST` is basically a RAID driver and this problem is often caused by a problem with a RAID driver.  Simplest solution if you are not using it to uninstall the driver.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows was correctly configured and the Errors and warnings were associated with ISCT events. Uninstalling iRST, however, got rid of the BSODs! Thank you so much!